# fontspec package conflicts with \textbf and \textit and \textsc

Tags: errors, fontspec

I have used `fontspec` package along with different packages to use some diacs such as ʾ ı ā ū, but when I use `\textit` or `textbf`, they do not function. When I deactivate the `fontspec` package, everything goes back to normal but the diacs does not appear.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{apacite}
% appendix
\usepackage{appendix}


\bibliographystyle{apacitex}

% try this package for ʾ ʿ
% \usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% package for times new roman font
\usepackage{times}
% package for different shapes 
%\usepackage{amssymb}
% single space or double space lines
\usepackage{setspace}
    \singlespacing
    %\doublespacing

% header 
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{my name\\ \itshape course name}
\rhead{\itshape \today}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% page number 
\rfoot{\thepage}
\usepackage{gb4e}

%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
%{\bfseries\scshape}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}


% to force indentation in the body
%\hspace{\parindent}
\begin{document}
\topskip=20pt

\begin{center}
    \large\textbf{my title }
    \normalsize
\end{center}

\begin{document}

\textit{hello}

\textbf{hello}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\gll Kasaba-t al-mu\textipa{G}ani-yat-u  qul\={u}b-a al-d\textipa{Z}amāhīr-.\\
 Gained-\scshape{3rd.sg.}   def-singer-\textsc{fem}-\textsc{nom}  heart-\textsc{poss} fans-\textsc{gen}.\\
\glt "The singer gained the fans' hearts."
\end{exe}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{times}` to begin with.

Comment: If you're going to use the `fontspec` package, why don't you use its `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont`, etc instructions to load fonts? If the only font-related package you're going to load is the `times` package, it makes no sense whatsoever to load the `fontspec` package.

Comment: Specifically, `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]`.